# varnish cache server: error 503 service unavailable

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, varnish

I install varnish (varnish-3.0.5 revision 1a89b1f), and Nexcess Turpentine (0.6.1) on One AWS EC2 instance and i change varnish listen to 80, and httpd listen 8080.

The front end error:

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable
Service Unavailable
Guru Meditation:
XID: 2017409829
Varnish cache server
```

The backend magento can be accessed by 8080.

The "netstat -ntl" output is:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::6379                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

I try to fix it by following tips:

- adjust first_byte_timeout and between_bytes_timeout
- "chkconfig --list varnish" to make sure varnish status is on
- "service iptables status" is closed
- set one bigger connect time out

But nothing helps.

I use varnishlog to find

```
FetchError   - http first read error: -1 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Following is default.vcl created by Turpentine

```
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.connect_timeout = 100s;
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 1200s;
}
backend admin {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 1200s;
}
acl crawler_acl {
"127.0.0.1";
}
acl debug_acl {
}
sub generate_session {
if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub(
req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1");
} else {
C{
char uuid_buf [50];
generate_uuid(uuid_buf);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ,
"\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:",
uuid_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; " + req.http.Cookie;
} else {
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
}
}
sub generate_session_expires {
C{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now);
now_tm.tm_sec += 3600;
mktime(&now_tm);
char date_buf [50];
strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP,
"\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:",
date_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
}
if (!true || req.http.Authorization ||
req.request !~ "^(GET|HEAD)$" ||
req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
return (pipe);
}
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(.*)//+(.*)", "\1/\2");
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/magento2/media/|/magento2/skin/|/magento2/js/|/magento2/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
if (req.url ~ "^(/magento2/media/|/magento2/skin/|/magento2/js/|/magento2/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend = admin;
return (pipe);
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/get(?:Block|FormKey)/") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
!(true || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
error 403 "External ESI requests are not allowed";
}
}
if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=") {
if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
} else {
call generate_session;
}
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
return (lookup);
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/magento2/media/|/magento2/skin/|/magento2/js/|/magento2/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php|\admin|/admin)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
return (pass);
}
if (req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
return (lookup);
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.Host) {
hash_data(req.http.Host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
return (hash);
}
sub vcl_hit {
}
sub vcl_fetch {
set req.grace = 15s;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Host = req.http.host;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-URL = req.url;
if (req.url ~ "^(/magento2/media/|/magento2/skin/|/magento2/js/|/magento2/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
unset beresp.http.Vary;
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
unset beresp.http.Expires;
unset beresp.http.Pragma;
unset beresp.http.Cache;
unset beresp.http.Age;
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (true &&
bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
set beresp.ttl = 28800s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800";
} elseif (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(req.http.Cookie,
"^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
}
set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
300s);
if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
}
} else {
set beresp.ttl = 600s;
}
}
}
return (deliver);
}
}
sub vcl_deliver {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
call generate_session_expires;
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
if (req.http.Host) {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
}
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") {
set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache";
}
if (true || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
} else {
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Host;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-URL;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With amazon supporter's help, we solve this issue by fix the backend default port in

**/etc/varnish/default.vcl**

we know, there are 3 default.vcl:

```
[root@ip-172-31-10-??? /]# find -name default.vcl
./etc/varnish/default.vcl
./var/www/html/magento/var/default.vcl
./usr/share/doc/varnish-3.0.5/examples/default.vcl
```

Mostly, we would just check the default.vcl in magento, and its backend default port would be configured to "8080"

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 60s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
}
```

And even we can see the backend default port is "80" in /etc/varnish/default.vcl, we believe it's nothing with the varnish.

But the issue has just been caused by this "80" port. Once we change this "80" to "8080", varnish begin to work so beautiful.

Comment: Good that you found it. Port 8080 has nothing to do with varnish , except it ensures that varnish forwards the traffic to the httpd instance on port 8080 (which is your backend). So it being in the default.vcl makes sense.

Comment: thanks, Marcel, we use couple hours to find it out. But, we still not totally understand why.